# Probability that kth order statistic is s given one of the values is s

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Let $U_1, \cdots,  U_n \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \textrm{Unif}[0, 1]$ and $0 < s < 1$.
Also, let us denote their order statistics as $U_{(1)},\cdots, U_{(n)}$.

I would like to compute the following conditional probability:
$$
\textrm{Pr}\left[U_{(k)} = s | s \in \{ U_1, \cdots, U_n \}\right]
$$

My attempt has been to come up with a recursive formula for this probability, by considering in which region $U_n$ lies, that is:

$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{Pr}\left[U_{(k)} = s | s \in \{ U_1, \cdots, U_n \}\right]
&=\textrm{Pr}[U_{(k)} = s, U_n > s | s \in \{ U_1, \cdots, U_{n-1} \}] \\
&\,+ \textrm{Pr}[U_{(k)} = s, U_n = s | s \in \{ U_1, \cdots, U_{n} \}] \\
&\,+ \textrm{Pr}[U_{(k)} = s, U_n < s | s \in \{ U_1, \cdots, U_{n-1} \}]
\end{align}
$$

However, I could not derive meaningful results from this, mostly because I have never worked with conditional probabilities where the condition has 'zero probability', as in this case where a single value is given to have appeared in the set of continuous random variables.

Thank you.

Comment: Because you are conditioning on a set of zero measure, you cannot get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thank you. I was half expecting that response, to be honest. Is there any way to circumvent that issue? For example, if n=2, then I think it is possible to express the condition as a cross on the unit square and compare the lengths.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is still no. There are two ways to look at the issue. One is through the definition of conditional expectation, which is a random variable defined only up to a set of measure zero. For example, your question could be interpreted as evaluating the random variable $P(U_{(k)} = s \mid 1(s\in \{U_1,\dots,U_n\}))$ for $\omega \in \{s\in \{U_1,\dots,U_n\}$. However, this latter set is null, and conditional expectation is only defined almost surely.

Comment: Another way is to somehow define sets of positive measure which approximate the set of null measure in a suitable sense and then take the limit, and assert that as your answer. This approach is not consistent with the definition of conditional probability/expectation, though it does yield an answer. However, one must be careful in interpreting the result because there may be multiple ways to approximate the set of zero measure, and generally, each way will yield a different answer. (Hence one reason one cannot define conditioning on a set of measure zero)

Comment: A well known demonstration of this issue is Borels paradox. Another construction is as follows. $E(X_1+X_2\mid X_1=X_2)$. The measure zero set in question here is $(X_1=X_2)$, which is clearly equal to $X_1/X_2=1$ or $X_1-X_2=0$. However, when you approximate, the events $1\leq X_1/X_2\leq 1+h$ and $0\leq X_1-X_2\leq h$ are different, and therefore lead to different limits.

Comment: Hmm... I see. I'll look out for zero-probability conditionals in the future. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_1, \cdots, U_n \}$ for simplicity. I will assume that $\mathbf{P}[ \,\cdot\, \mid s \in \mathcal{U}]$ is defined via the weak limit

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[ \cdot \mid s \in \mathcal{U} ]
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \mathbf{P}[ \cdot \mid \mathcal{U} \cap \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s) \neq \varnothing ],
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s) = (s-\varepsilon, s+\varepsilon)$ is the open interval of radius $\varepsilon$ about $s$.

> *Remark.* Like what @Andrew Zhang mentioned in the comments, this is by no means a canonical way of defining the conditional distribution (and we do not expect such thing to exist). Whether this particular implementation of $\mathbf{P}[ \,\cdot\, \mid s \in \mathcal{U}]$ makes sense and/or is useful in OP's setting or not, hinges on how it is going to be used in OP's context.

In order to compute the law of $U_{(k)}$ under $\mathbf{P}[ \,\cdot\, \mid s \in \mathcal{U}]$, let us consider an arbitrary smooth test function $h \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}([0, 1])$. Then we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[ h(U_{(k)}) \mid \mathcal{U} \cap \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s) \neq \varnothing ]
&= \frac{\mathbf{E}[ h(U_{(k)}) \mathbf{1}_{\{\mathcal{U} \cap \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s) \neq \varnothing\}} ]}{\mathbf{P}[ \mathcal{U} \cap \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s) \neq \varnothing ]} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{E}[ h(U_{(k)}) \mid U_{(j)} \in \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s) ] \mathbf{P}[U_{(j)} \in \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s)] + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{P}[U_{(j)} \in \mathcal{B}_{\varepsilon}(s)] + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{E}[ h(U_{(k)}) \mid U_{(j)} = s ] f_{U_{(j)}}(s) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{U_{(j)}}(s) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)}.
\end{align*}

By letting $\varepsilon \to 0^+$, this reduces to

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}[ h(U_{(k)}) \mid s \in \mathcal{U} ]
&= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mathbf{E}[ h(U_{(k)}) \mid U_{(j)} = s ] f_{U_{(j)}}(s)}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{U_{(j)}}(s)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{U_{(j)}}(s)} \biggl[ \sum_{j\in[n]\setminus\{k\}} \int_{0}^{1} h(u) f_{U_{(k)},U_{(j)}}(u, s) \, \mathrm{d}u + h(s) f_{U_{(k)}}(s) \biggr]
\end{align*}

In particular, this shows that the law of $U_{(k)}$ under the law $\mathbf{P}[ \cdot \mid s \in \mathcal{U} ]$ is of mixed type with

$$ \mathbf{P}[ U_{(k)} = s \mid s \in \mathcal{U} ]
= \frac{f_{U_{(k)}}(s)}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} f_{U_{(j)}}(s)}. $$

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for the explanation! The last result sure gives the Bayesian-ness vibes. I'll need to check if that interpretation applies to my problem. Thank you again!